# Decrypting an AES encrypted JSON file in Python, with no IV

Tags: javascript, python, json, encryption, aes

Trying to mod a game for personal use (Turn on mouse control, remove menu/dialogue restrictions)
To mod the files I need to **decrypt a JSON file.**
It's contents should be generic game info but instead shows these Japanese characters when accessed.
`ﾏﾏﾏﾏﾏｱｺｲｳｺｶﾏﾏﾏﾏﾏ`
Notepads guesses this is Shift JIS encoding, I pursued that line of thought and came up empty handed.
VSCode and Visual Studio can't make heads or tails of the JSON, and** keep adding filler bytes** with rhombused question marks in UTF-8.
[VSCode Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkidc.png)

With Shift Jis encoding enabled, the original string appears and more Japanese(?) characters show up, still with question marks.
[VSCode Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzWRa.png)

Selecting all of the text, thousands of characters, and copy-pasting it into Notepads, shows the original 16 character string again: ﾏﾏﾏﾏﾏｱｺｲｳｺｶﾏﾏﾏﾏﾏ

Rummaging in the game folder I found a "Decryption.js" that looks like this:

```
// Encrypted source for asset decryption functions.
let decryptionAESKey = "02f3ffa287f78ba68c60f24f79c6fb18ce32b4ebaadac11af5ace8c67a50ae9f";
let decryptionSource = "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";
```

Supposedly this decrypts all of the game files, PNGs, OGGs, and JSONs. I'm only interested in the System JSON since that's where my settings are.

I pursued AES Decryption but this file **does not mention an IV** which I understand is needed.
I wrote this code in Python using the cryprography library, but without understanding what "decryptionSource" is, it doesn't do anything.
decryprionSource is 4703 characters, isn't it too big to be an IV?

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
import json

def decrypt_aes_cbc(file_path, key):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        encrypted_data = file.read()

    # There is no IV
    iv = encrypted_data[:16]
    ciphertext = encrypted_data[16:]

    cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CBC(iv), backend=default_backend())
    decryptor = cipher.decryptor()
    decrypted_data = decryptor.update(ciphertext) + decryptor.finalize()

    try:
        decrypted_json = json.loads(decrypted_data.decode('utf-8'))
        return decrypted_json
    except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
        print(f"Error decoding JSON: {e}")
        return None

def main():
    key = bytes.fromhex("02f3ffa287f78ba68c60f24f79c6fb18ce32b4ebaadac11af5ace8c67a50ae9f")

    file_path = input("Enter the path to the AES encrypted JSON file: ")

    decrypted_data = decrypt_aes_cbc(file_path, key)

    if decrypted_data is not None:
        print("\nDecrypted JSON data:")
        print(json.dumps(decrypted_data, indent=2))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

it prints :
`ValueError: The length of the provided data is not a multiple of the block length.`

All files are provided in this link if you want to review them:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BUzACflcfEtQk5Nf6V14h8S5gZRsof9N/view

What am I missing?

I tried converting from Shift JIS encoding to UTF-8 but it did not produce relevant data.
I tried to pursue AES decryption as hinted by the js file, but I do not know what to do with decryptionSource which is a key piece of information.
I'm new to all of this and just learned about AES encryption.
The key is a 64 hex so it must be 256-bit, I don't know which AES mode to use so I'll try all 6.

---

**Edit:**

I tried decrypting in python:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import unpad
import binascii

def aes_decrypt(encrypted_data, aes_key):
    # Decode hexadecimal encoded data
    decoded_data = binascii.unhexlify(encrypted_data)

    # Take the first 16 bytes as IV
    iv = decoded_data[:16]

    # Decode hexadecimal encoded AES key
    key = binascii.unhexlify(aes_key)

    # Create an AES cipher object mode cbc
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)

    # Decrypt the data and unpad
    decrypted_data = unpad(cipher.decrypt(decoded_data[16:]), AES.block_size)

    return decrypted_data.decode('utf_8')
    #return decrypted_data


# Example data (replace with your actual data)
encrypted_data = "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"
aes_key = "02f3ffa287f78ba68c60f24f79c6fb18ce32b4ebaadac11af5ace8c67a50ae9f"

# Decrypt and print the result
decrypted_result = aes_decrypt(encrypted_data, aes_key)
print("Decrypted Data:", decrypted_result)
```

it prints errors that vary based on the encoding used,

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-32-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-3: code point not in range(0x110000)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 10-11: illegal UTF-16 surrogate
UnicodeDecodeError: 'shift_jis' codec can't decode byte 0xfb in position 6: illegal multibyte sequence
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xda in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

@Topaco theorizes this is due to a corrupted block of data.

All files are provided in this link if you want to review them:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BUzACflcfEtQk5Nf6V14h8S5gZRsof9N/view

What am I missing?

My assumptions:
-Picked Hex over Base64, discussed with @MaartenBodewes
-Using CBC mode of operation
-That the data is PKCS7 padded and needs "unpad('')"

I'm new to all of this and just learned about AES encryption.
Keeping the other question for posterity.

Comment: `decryptionSource` is a ciphertext that can be decrypted with `decryptionAESKey`. If the first block (16 bytes) of `decryptionSource` is interpreted as IV, the first block of the decrypted data is corrupted. This indicates a wrong IV. It is possible that `decryptionSource` is corrupted, that the preceding block of `decryptionSource` has to be processed somehow before it can be used as IV, etc. Nevertheless, around 99% can be decrypted.

Comment: @Topaco Would you recommend going ahead and using that block as an IV, or decrypt with ECB and forego IV altogether?

Comment: `System.json` does not appear to be a ciphertext at all. The content of `System.json` does not equal a multiple of the blocksize of 16 bytes which at least rules out block cipher modes like CBC. In addition, an examination of the file content in a hex editor indicates that it is not a *pure* ciphertext (which still leaves open the possibility that a ciphertext is somehow *embedded*). For this, there are too many sequences that do not appear random.

Comment: Without information about the format/structure of the file, it might be difficult to identify a ciphertext (if one is present at all). Also keep in mind that `decryptionAESKey` does not necessarily have to be the decryption key that corresponds to `System.json`.

Comment: I'm familiar with this game engine as I've modded in it before, if by file structure you mean what a regular unencrypted System.json should look like, I can send you one for reference.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Cc3nSZtzXmI9a0vocjQCga28yP-mKMYS/view

Comment: No, I mean the format/structure of the *encrypted* files. Take a look at e.g. *Weapons.json*. The first block most probably does not correspond to a ciphertext (not enough randomness). It may be the IV. In addition, the length does not correspond to an integer multiple of the blocksize of 16 bytes. It is possible that only part of the data is the ciphertext or that no block cipher mode is applied. As you can see, without knowing the format (and the details of the encryption) you can only guess.

Comment: I see, I'll follow your theory and try to decrypt the decrypter's source itself, then see if the decrypter can handle the enceypted files as seemingly advertised.

Comment: New code: 
Throws this error:

ValueError: Incorrect IV length (it must be 16 bytes long)
I'm making several assumptions here:

-The decrypted data is assumed to be in UTF-8 encoding
-binascii.unhexlify(data), I just learned about AES encryption laat night and I'm using this line as the "normal" thing to do. Does it apply to my case? If it's Hex it has to be decoded right?
-I'm not sure if the data or key is Hex or Base64. The key is 64 characters so I assume it's Hex.

Comment: *...New code: Throws this error: ...* Sorry, I can't say anything about it since I don't know what your new code looks like. `decryptionAESKey` and `decryptionSource` are hex encoded. Which encoding makes sense for the decrypted data depends on how the binary plaintext for the encryption was created (which I do not know). If it was generated as UTF-8 encoding of a text/string, the decrypted data can be UTF-8 decoded.

Comment: @Topaco You did close the other question with the new code and the error as a dupe of this one. That was a different question and with related questions added to it. Please reopen that one. It's not a dupe of this question even if it is about an iteration of the same code.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes 
I managed to decrypt the data, thank you both, but .decode('utf-8') does not work, giving this error:  UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xda in position 0: invalid continuation byte
This is the data printed with .decode removed : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N0joCaQO5BvAM9fbV9_lCbw_LxblAKIX/view
The original file that contained this data is a JavaScript file named Decrypter.js, the data itself is the source of that JavaScript file, meant to decrypt other assets.
Does knowing that it's JavaScript code originally, help in getting it to look that way?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - Why shouldn't this be a duplicate? This question is about decrypting the ciphertext 0x40b6..., just like the new question. This has already been answered in the first comment of this question here. It would have made more sense if the OP had attached his new (wrong) attempt to this question in order to be able to finish the analysis started here instead of starting a new post. Besides, the new questions have already been asked here (but could only be answered in general terms due to the missing code).

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kdtCEbs_xLzjHMz8-3yTr_0IP4s01HZo/view?usp=sharing
updated code that throws that error. Separated operations for readability.

Comment: Please don't post relevant information in comments, but edit the question and append the new information there (this also applies to revised code). Also, don't post screenshots, but a format that is compatible with copy and paste.

Comment: Besides, I already described the decryption in my first comment and pointed out the corrupted first block of the decrpted data. But it makes no sense to have this discussion in two places. Either you post your most recent code here, to which your last comment refers, or you continue the discussion in your new post.

Comment: I'll edit this post, but the reason I made the other post was because I genuinely thought that I'd run into a new problem, one unrelated to my query here. Especially since the entire premise of this post prpved wrong; I'm trying to decrypt a JavaScript file, this post talks about a JSON.

Comment: @Topaco post edited, you did describe the encyption but you did not provide a solution my friend. You mentioned that regardless of that corrupted block, 99% can still be decrypted. How do I go about decrypting 99% of the data? just randomly delete a chunk of it? I don't know enough to figure that out on my own. Would you kindly provide a method?

Comment: *...but you did not provide a solution my friend...* If the information is not enough, you have to say so. I am not a clairvoyant. *...I don't know enough to figure that out on my own. Would you kindly provide a method?...* Your post does not contain the information to answer why the common procedure does not work (for this reason I have listed some possibilities).

Comment: So do you have a way to decrypt 99% of the data? @Topaco

Answer (score 0):

##### Decryption of ciphertext from Decryption.js

Since the IV is required for decryption and is not a secret, it is common practice to concatenate IV and ciphertext in the order `IV|ciphertext`. Lacking more detailed information on the algorithm, it is reasonable to first assume the same in this case.
The Python code posted in the *Edit* section does exactly this. Key and ciphertext appear to be hex encoded and are hex decoded accordingly in the Python code.

The result of the decryption confirms the assumptions made: Apart from the first block, the plaintext is a byte sequence that is UTF-8 decodable. In this way, around 1-(16 bytes/2344 bytes) = 99 % of the ciphertext can be successfully decrypted. The UTF-8 decoded plaintext (from the second block onwards) is:

```
Decrypter.decryptArrapZe2JJCW1xKeFE6L7wmFbKrPj8XoA0e6zK8OiTCMlF3lUAM3zWwhJer){if(!arrayBvvJoSf8DqqCpnBfCHRrqbHf2WJ8OTp3d289ujji84tint8Array=nUsHpUZvrGF6y3B8PK7PeO7sbSaMRfCmZ8c4DzjeLbBgeTMiCIreturnthis.decryptUAZkAhuC8gO2B7Vv2WYAqxAo06qgPF5nZ7xL;};DecxxdbtLjyziTYeK6lWyU0q91vvLqVd8rMbmKRW2cIo7QPyNOmu7RuMF9Rufunction(uint8Array){ZIOuFwwfIYmYjN4fKm3JPr7zpQgUvlRPrVcu02YcSYeoitDecoder().decode(uint8ArsBvHPjTf1Cmkj3vvSjlk2LQiEXGy70tQOFT5vprc0(header!==z8Vzm4kffnHKak1QAg8OTjprL9w8EaYo5DpFCqbint8Array;}orIfsoYrl962pIc65cZwvp5FWrieNITcNiLaGgfI68jMEXFakuYmxr8Of3];vardatpos=1UTnq9nFOD6F1oEGK1DDELftiPObz0oytes=[0].concatJaEN0Lwc6aBKPia3WhTu86PMFv03c9oNR7vHay.slice(1ZLRa11OMXKnieKw4oQk0Xr04KI7IYB3v97hnJnmobznQXRos=datpos;forfIfTlI2hXN0O8pKBb2isj3fJSuRSWR5iqp8os+=ofs;if(pos>Bz63QEpOD2903GA3ECuWXSUqzyQXA7xKyyu8fxtbreak;}u2gQYSGk24MBGqo2LAYvS9TsHLw5jkqbos]-1)%256;U9cKQiZRfa7yvbTdOKiGWHwYMjHMmice(datpos);};DecryptemHmUlMNhysCQuDorKkKZ3ZgFgOPO0g20lLjLT0PzsIukction(uint8Array){varhelA2XCCdHy3Z5IYQ0TosH8dxnGdecode(uint8Array.slice(0,SIGlO2IbCGmKsTYVHq1j6uEAaVT1WvF4Py8jTKv==XORENCODEz3NVbnzXymWRmJL95rCS2A38VXq8oFLasXtY4KBzF8VLDdJC7varhlen=XOREhZjJLoNu72nQoteUtcWS3Iousiuint8ArraUV3oyoUZtrsVWJ0JEDS0nqF6qm9AeF2gZDbHlhAE7SgHTKLvopz6nZsxopWGint8Array(uiphJdCChFS1ddkdrnFYK4CCT8iQEjKyJk7it55bJo7-1);for(vari=0;i<lvntjevN5eUEYN9Cx7K8oYTDr0tXNy3hg7iYj17tR8oPwbf84ruDpVdata[i]=uintamzdW8IEVm4gfW2FAEVdCo9MNkXE9RjtbmUMyCE8Cbyte=(byte+1)%256;}0LiPCxWRYWwxVKnsPZ3PuIIeRn5RzRoXhyDataManager.loclRjoUHPkGlFVoFfBlCDiUXLYipmbT0g2hoqHUJ5KYVuddP9P7smBVVLUPRTe,src){varxhr=ner6JMDo2j7muduBmCUkDbHE6Lrurl="data/"+srK662r9ovhR6Bp9crFpXmfGfXNSVOWIP75arxhr.overrideMimeType("applcrhp3rT3Qcob2rqHRDSxWOjCR9J1RPPsi0lNJ29jCGMBJ.responseType="arraybuffer";SdpKEWrHo5b0Wi5ZrDIVyPj4gyGrGhwzmlghYsO{if(x20hfEIhvNcbx2HuBCvE2ZekljNwsGqPPsult="";varutsOqZUA87F7Cttvkv6Btw0ar.response);varheader=DdUzvKKCnP4KSvVloFPcwwNCgVcDhYi4nllaokubJhwK3JQszizu8Data.slice(0hikyJUhDefLrvfRxtK0ILDoffD198v4N3mo9ePorSPXK2PLyxvHlvjzJff(header===Xk0FTPkSqMdub8faO5rXfDc76=Decrypter.xoIvDKKoV0pfkUZJKJN5l6iEData);}result=newTLqAUjyZe8eh6eRWiJwYQBpUHl0vR2yZtvata);winksFemDkEAT71OP7clRnOOOmaxAnNMj18esult);DataManagerrpcfzCfdKiEl1gu58gwXHOAdlVE8};xhr.onerror=thiHkHNbIdw3tN98na3eKT3VeI7nTTt{DataManager._errorUk39fwHulQe0HzEGLVeZfDXGUBWXmKurl;};window[name]=lUYrSp1PWwDNuEeJNeWhQEEff
```

Regarding the other encodings you tested, UTF-16LE, UTF-32LE and Shift JIS, the decrypted data is not compatible with any of them, which is in accordance with the error messages you observed.

As already mentioned, the first block is not UTF-8 compliant (see section *Corruption of first block* for this). Therefore, in the Python code, the first block must not be UTF-8 decoded, otherwise the *UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode...* error message would be thrown, in accordance with your observation.
To exclude the first block from the UTF-8 decoding, the following change in the Python code is necessary: `return decrypted_data[16:].decode('utf_8')`.

##### Verification of decryption

The encryption used (AES/CBC without MAC) does not allow any authentication of the data, so that only indirect conclusions can be drawn as to whether the decryption was successful and the assumptions made (AES, CBC, PKCS#7 padding, hex encoding of key and data) were correct.

Nevertheless, it can be assumed with a probability bordering on certainty that the decryption is correct (except for the first block). In the event of incorrect decryption, the result would resemble a random byte sequence. However, this is not the case here, as the data represents valid UTF-8 byte sequences.
The padding bytes also support this. These consist of 8 times 0x08 bytes, which corresponds to a valid PKCS#7 padding (a random generation of such a byte sequence has a probability bordering on zero).

It is striking that the plaintext contains many meaningless alphanumeric sequences. These are not an indication of a faulty decryption, as the latter would not lead to alternating meaningful and meaningless sequences, but would result in a single random byte sequence (which cannot be decoded with a charset encoding like UTF-8). We can only speculate about the meaningless byte sequences of the decrypted data; they may have their origin in an [obfuscation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation) of the plaintext that took place before the encryption.

##### Corruption of first block

The first block is hex encoded 0xda7cae2dbb12fb4faa867ed8ab8ee554, which can e.g. be determined with the following change in the Python code: `return decrypted_data[:16].hex()`.
This byte sequence is not UTF-8 compatible, which indicates a corrupted block with regard to the rest of the data. Corruption of the first block in CBC mode is an indication that the IV is not correct. Another possibility is that the first block of the actual ciphertext is corrupted.

A wrong IV means that the IV itself is corrupted or simply that the assumption of the concatenation (`IV|ciphertext`) is wrong.
The concatenation is ultimately only a convention. It would also be conceivable to have a constant IV (although insecure) of unknown value or that the first block is only used to derive the actual IV in some manner. The latter would be unusual, but cannot be ruled out (*unusual*, because the easiest way with reasonable security is to generate a random IV and pass it directly with the ciphertext instead of a cumbersome and unnecessary derivation).

Unfortunately, without knowing the plaintext of the first block, there is no way to determine the correct IV on the basis of the known data (at least not without reasonable effort). Therefore, it must ultimately be stated that the information posted in the question is not sufficient to determine the correct IV or the algorithm to derive it.

##### Overall objective

The overall goal of this question is to decrypt the encrypted *System.json* file, which is hex encoded:

```
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
```

When this file is loaded with a hex editor, it becomes apparent that the data as a whole does not resemble a random byte sequence, more precisely there are regions in between in which the same patterns, e.g. 0x92D0185290D8125098D21058 or 0x1D41AB87EF5991D51743A38DED519BD71F49A185E75393DD, are repeated many times. This is not compatible with a ciphertext generated with AES/CBC.
However, it is still possible that the ciphertext (or even several ciphertexts) is embedded somewhere in this data. In order to be able to say more here, it is necessary to obtain information about the structure of such a file, which unfortunately is not available.
So, it can be practically ruled out that the file as a whole represents a ciphertext and that a decryption of this supposed ciphertext would be successful with AES/CBC.

It should also be kept in mind that even if a ciphertext could be extracted from the file, it is unclear which key to use or which algorithm. There is no compelling reason that the data can be decrypted with the key from the *Decryption.js* file (0x02f3...) or the AES/CBC algorithm (at least there is no compelling reason from the information posted).

##### What information is needed to fully answer the question without guessing?

With regard to the first part, it would be important to know which IV is used or how it can be derived. Instead of the IV, the plaintext of the first block would also be sufficient, because the IV can be calculated from key, plaintext and ciphertext.
With regard to the second part, it would be important to know the structure of the *System.json* file, which encryption algorithm is used and which key is required for decryption.
The most ideal way to answer both parts is the corresponding documentation or alternatively the source code that creates the ciphertext contained in the *Decryption.json* file and that generates the *System.json* file, respectively.

Comment: Grateful for the edited post and detailed answer @Topaco